# Error binding values for Oracle SQL command in Python

Tags: python, oracle, binding, cx-oracle

I'm getting an error when executing the below and despite trying to work out what Im doing wrong, I cant get my head around this. Accept this is probably really straight forward and a syntax error?

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

aValue = 'all_tables'
sql = "select * from sometable = :myField"
cursor.execute(sql, myField = aValue)
```

my intention is to subsequently make aValue a single item from a list in a for loop statement

Thanks

Comment: I think your command is incomplete maybe, should be `select * from sometable where myField= :myField`

Comment: I believe that syntax puts a where condition on an attribute on sometable, where as i'm trying to parametrise the from statement to be able to be changed from a for loop

Comment: please, try execute native query on database directly `select * from sometable = 'all_tables'` to simulate this error, I believe method execute dont put `where` condition, its use native query

Comment: trying  `select banner as "oracle version" from v$version = 'teste'` 
 in tthis site a compiler online I have the same error https://rextester.com/l/oracle_online_compiler

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it’s been answered in a comment on the following site

https://www.toolbox.com/tech/oracle/question/using-bind-variables-in-from-clause-042108/

In short it looks like I’m getting the error because I’m trying to use a binding variable on a from clause, which isn’t possible